# ArcGIS JS-API click on Graphic and exceute code

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Currently I can click on the GraphicsLayer and I can see an array of all my Graphics added there.

```
const layerMarkers = new GraphicsLayer({id: layerId});
this.map.addLayer(layerMarkers);
const graphic = new Graphic(point, imageSymbol, null, null);
layerMarkers.add(graphic);
```

But how can extract the data from that Graphic and do something with that data? I want to create a InfoTemplate only for that graphic.

```
layerMarkers.graphics[0].setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
```

I don't wan't to call `.graphics[0]` that way, I want to pick the array from clickin on the Graphic.

I was trying some `this.map.on('click', (evt) =>` but what I need is to click on a specific Graphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup a [click event listener on the GraphicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#event-click). Something like this:

```
layerMarkers.on('click', function(evt) {
  var graphic = evt.graphic;
  console.log("Clicked graphic:", graphic);
});
```